# SendGrid single send not getting scheduled

Tags: python, email, twilio, sendgrid

I am trying to send a newsletter email using SendGrid Python API.
when filling the `send_at` with either `now` or any other working
SendGrid [api documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/schedule-single-send) states the following

> To schedule a Single Send, you must pass a date string in ISO 8601 time format (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ) using the required send_at field. For example, the ISO 8601 format for 9:00 AM UTC on May 6, 2020 would be 2020-05-06T09:00:00Z. You may also pass the string "now" to send the Single Send immediately.

- when using now, the code fails and I get the following message
  `{'errors': [{'field': '', 'message': 'json could not be unmarshalled'}]}`
- when using a time that is manually written, the code works, and the single send is registered, but checking the portal, it shows as a draft instead of scheduled.
  I cant figure what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

It's a two part process, use Schedule Single Send.
https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/schedule-single-send

Best way to do it:

1. Do not add send_to to your initial request, once the single send has been created collect the ID
2. Use send_to with schedule single send for either a future date or 'now'